# Intercambiar posicion entre banderas

Tags: html, css

El siguiente codigo muestra una serie de banderas, al pasar click sobre la bandera de inglaterra, se muestran más banderas como:

- la de alemania,
- holanda,
- etc.

¿Cómo hago para que la bandera cambie de posicion por la otra al hacer click en ella?

Me explico, si eligo la de alemania, tiene que cambiar de posicion con la de inglaterra, y asi sucesivamente con las demas.

El codigo HTML muestra una lista de banderas que son Inglaterra, Francia, Italia, Alemania y Holanda. El codigo Css, es el diseño de la lista, haciendolo un menu despegable.

```css
<style type="text/css">
   
   * {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
   }
   
   #header {
    margin:auto;
    width:500px;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   }
   
   ul, ol {
    list-style:none;
   }
   
   .nav > li {
    float:left;
   }
   
   .nav li a {
    background-color:#000;
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:10px 12px;
    display:block;
   }
   
   .nav li a:hover {
    background-color:#434343;
   }
   
   .nav li ul {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    min-width:50px;
   }
   
   .nav li:hover > ul {
    display:block;
   }
   
   .nav li ul li {
    position:relative;
   }
   
   .nav li ul li ul {
    right:-140px;
    top:0px;
   }
   
  </style>
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Menu Desplegable</title>
  <link href='https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css' rel='stylesheet'/>
  
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="header">
   <ul class="nav">
    
    <li><a href=""><img src="https://i.imgur.com/JfcgMq3.png" width="28" height="28" style="left:-5px;"/><i class="fas fa-caret-down" style="font-size:20px; color:#ffffff;"></i></a>
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/skxVw7A.png" width="28" height="28" style="left:-5px;"/></a></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/iZzY1wO.png"width="28" height="28" style="left:-5px;"/></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/fVxPzVF.png" width="28" height="28" style="left:-5px;"/></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/Qaf0696.png" width="28" height="28" style="left:-5px;"/></a>
       
      </li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    
    </li>
   
   </ul>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: No he intentado con Javascript porque no poseo los conocimientos suficientes para hacer el codigo que haga lo que quiero, por eso estoy publicando para que me puedan ayudar con eso.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo primero que haría es colocar un `id` a mi etiqueta `a`, que seria la bandera `principal`, también agregaría una `class` para el resto de las las banderas, en este caso la llamare `flats`. Una vez hecho esto con ayuda de `JQuery` crearía la función `click` para la clase `flats`, en donde intercambiaría las imagenes tal como deseas.

**Ejemplo funcional:**

```js
$(".flats").click(function(){
  var src_principal=$("#principal img").attr("src");
  var src_flat=$(this).children("img").attr("src");
  $("#principal img").attr("src",src_flat);
  $(this).children("img").attr("src",src_principal);
})
```

```css
<style type="text/css">
   
   * {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
   }
   
   #header {
    margin:auto;
    width:500px;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   }
   
   ul, ol {
    list-style:none;
   }
   
   .nav > li {
    float:left;
   }
   
   .nav li a {
    background-color:#000;
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:10px 12px;
    display:block;
   }
   
   .nav li a:hover {
    background-color:#434343;
   }
   
   .nav li ul {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    min-width:50px;
   }
   
   .nav li:hover > ul {
    display:block;
   }
   
   .nav li ul li {
    position:relative;
   }
   
   .nav li ul li ul {
    right:-140px;
    top:0px;
   }
   
  </style>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Menu Desplegable</title>
  <link href='https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css' rel='stylesheet'/>
  
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="header">
   <ul class="nav">
    
    <li>
            <a href="" id="principal" ><img src="https://i.imgur.com/JfcgMq3.png" width="28" height="28" style="left:-5px;"/>                 <i class="fas fa-caret-down" style="font-size:20px; color:#ffffff;"></i>
            </a>
     <ul>
      <li>
                <a href="#" class="flats"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/skxVw7A.png" width="28" height="28" style="left:-5px;"/></a>
            </li>
      <li>
                <a href="#" class="flats"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/iZzY1wO.png"width="28" height="28" style="left:-5px;"/></a>
            </li>
      <li>
                <a href="#" class="flats"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/fVxPzVF.png" width="28" height="28" style="left:-5px;"/></a>
            </li>
      <li>
                <a href="#" class="flats"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/Qaf0696.png" width="28" height="28" style="left:-5px;"/></a>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    
    </li>
   
   </ul>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias #Shassain :)

Answer (score 0):

Ya que manifiestas no saber de JS para comenzar haré el sigueinte aporte:

- Le asignas un id al elemento `img` principal o que aparece al inicio y que es al cual le quiere modificar el `src`
- Al `ul` que contiene el listado de banderas que son las cuales a través de un `click` pasen su imagen a la principal el das una clase
- Con JS puro recuperamos en 2 variables a los 2 puntos mencionados anteriormente
- Vigilamos el evento *click* del ul que contiene a las imágenes para saber quien de ellas disparó dicho evento
- Por dentro de la función tomamos a la variable que contiene a la bandera principal y le modificamos con `setAttribute` el atributo `src`

Quedando así:

```html
    <html>
     <head>
      <title>Menu Desplegable</title>
      <link href='https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css' rel='stylesheet'/>
      <style type="text/css">
       
       * {
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
       }
       
       #header {
        margin:auto;
        width:500px;
        font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
       }
       
       ul, ol {
        list-style:none;
       }
       
       .nav > li {
        float:left;
       }
       
       .nav li a {
        background-color:#000;
        color:#fff;
        text-decoration:none;
        padding:10px 12px;
        display:block;
       }
       
       .nav li a:hover {
        background-color:#434343;
       }
       
       .nav li ul {
        display:none;
        position:absolute;
        min-width:50px;
       }
       
       .nav li:hover > ul {
        display:block;
       }
       
       .nav li ul li {
        position:relative;
       }
       
       .nav li ul li ul {
        right:-140px;
        top:0px;
       }
       
      </style>
     </head>
     <body>
      <div id="header">
       <ul class="nav">
        
        <li><a href="#"><img id="principal" src="https://i.imgur.com/JfcgMq3.png" width="28" height="28" style="left:-5px;"/><i class="fas fa-caret-down" style="font-size:20px; color:#ffffff;"></i></a>
         <ul class="contenedor-banderas">
          <li><a  href="#"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/skxVw7A.png" width="28" height="28" style="left:-5px;"/></a></a></li>
          <li><a  href="#"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/iZzY1wO.png"width="28" height="28" style="left:-5px;"/></a></li>
          <li><a  href="#"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/fVxPzVF.png" width="28" height="28" style="left:-5px;"/></a></li>
          <li><a  href="#"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/Qaf0696.png" width="28" height="28" style="left:-5px;"/></a>
           
          </li>
         </ul>
        </li>
        
        </li>
       
       </ul>
      </div>
     </body>
    <script>
      let bandera = document.querySelector("#principal")
      let banderas = document.querySelector(".contenedor-banderas")
      
      banderas.addEventListener("click", (evento) => {
        bandera.setAttribute("src", evento.target.src)
      })
    </script>
    </html>
```

**Lecturas necesarias de revisión**

- [event.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Event/target)

Comment: Gracias!!, ambas respuestas solucionan mi problema, tengo una consulta, si todas las imagenes llevan un enlace, al ir a ese enlace, la imagen vuelve a ser la principal y no cambia a las otras, he creado este tema ya que estoy haciendo un menu desplegable con banderas, que sea tipo traductor.

Comment: @Husdady yo he probado con mi respuesta colocando enlaces a diferentes páginas web y funciona bien con cada una es decir manda al enlace correspondiente

Comment: Te pongo como ejemplo mi blog, bueno todas las banderas tienen el mismo enlace, al hacer clic en una de ellas, recarga la pagina pero sigue estando la bandera de inglaterra y no la otra, puedes comprobarlo entrando en mi blog en la parte izquierda esta ese pequeño menu desplegable, ¿me ayudarias solo en eso? Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: puedes verificar el codigo en el siguiente enlace: https://nutricionysaludpersonal.blogspot.com/p/blog-page_14.html que la bandera no cambia al recargar la pagina, si le quito enlace funciona normal, esta en la parte izquierda, al hacer clic en la bandera de italia, recarga la pagina pero sige saliendo la de inglaterra, ayudame en eso @BetaM